# php exec not working along with wapiti

Tags: php, python-2.7, exec, wapiti

I have a python script (wap.py) from which I am calling wapiti asynchronously using Popen. Command for it in wap.py:
p = Popen("python  wapiti domainName", shell = True)
When I am running wap.py, it is executing completely fine.

But when I am running it using php exec, it doesn't work.
Command from php file : exec("python wap.py")

Comment: To help readability, wrap any code snippets in the Code Formatting block.  It's the **{}** symbol when you're writing your question.  That preserves formatting and highlights keywords, as well as making it much more readable.

Comment: Ohk thanks. Will take that into account while posting next questions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the php.ini to see if there's anything set for `disable_functions`. If you're using PHP CLI for the script, you can execute the following command in the shell:
`php -i | grep disable_functions`

Also make sure `wap.py` has execute permissions.

Comment: Yes, I looked into the php.ini and there is nothing set for disable_functions.

Comment: Got the error. Error is with the wapiti itself and not with the php. Had to add one extra line in wapiti to make it work.